# How can I create a radial animation that hollows out a shape from the inside?

Tags: unity

I want to create the radial/circular animation seen in the explosions in [this .gif of Flat Heroes](https://twitter.com/GustavJacobsson/status/894553190041092096).

I made an image using Illustrator of a radial ring (as below), but I'm not sure if this is the right approach. How can this be done?

Also, I would like to know how this could be extended to make similar animations for other shapes like squares and triangles.

[image: Ring created in Illustrator]

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? What have you tried so far? Can you post your code? Have you looked through the animation frame-by-frame to see what's happening?

Comment: @user1118321 I just updated the question. I know that it is required on this forum to provide what one has done, but to be honest with you I really don't know how to go about this so I haven't done much apart from preparing an image that I think could help.

Comment: Three things: 1) So the effect you're looking for is this: the explosion starts out as a circle then it gets transparent from the center in a circular fashion 2.) Can you use shaders? 3.) What's the problem with simply animating it? Even gimp should suffice.

Comment: @Bálint I know shader basics. I've not used gimp before. Thanks for explaining how the process of the animation, but how precisely can I create this animation? I would really appreciate some clear guidelines, preferably using shaders with some code if necessary for clarity. I am quite blank on how to do this that's why I've not stated what I've been able to achieve in the question.

Comment: Gimp is just a free picture editing tool, similar to photoshop. You can't really make the animation bettet if you procedurally generate it. I'll post hoe you do it with a shader once I get home

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a circular cutout we can do this with a little radius math and no textures at all. But since you mention wanting to extend to squares and triangles, I'll show a more general approach.

[image: Animated particle system with star-shaped particles that wipe away from the inside.]

First we create a texture in the shape we want, with a gradient falloff toward the interior. This gradient should follow the shape of the perimeter - we'll use it to control the shape of the inner cutout. For a circle, this can be a simple radial gradient.

[image: Star-shaped gradient, white at the perimeter of the star and dark grey at the center.]

Next we write a shader that reads this texture, as well as a threshold parameter, and displays only parts of the gradient that are brighter than the threshold as opaque, and everything darker as translucent, like so:

```
Shader "Unlit/RadialParticle"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // Treat this material as transparent
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" }
        LOD 100

        // Set up alpha blending
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                // Vertex color field 
                // (used by the particle system to tint)
                fixed4 color : COLOR0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                // Pass through color information to fragment
                fixed4 color : COLOR0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                // Pass our color parameter through to the fragment
                o.color = v.color;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                // Hide any part of the image that's darker than 
                // the _Cutout parameter
                col.a = saturate((col.r - i.color.a) * 10.0f);

                // Replace the visible color of the image
                // with the particle color
                col.rgb = i.color.rgb;

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Attach your shader to a material and configure it with your gradient texture and you're off to the races. :)

Here I've configured the shader to work in a particle system, reading the threshold from the vertex colour's alpha channel. That let me use the particle system's "Color Over Lifetime" curves to create the animation above quickly.

If you need to do this with just a single quad, you could instead expose `_Cutout` material parameter, and vary that material property via script.

```
Shader "Unlit/RadialSprite"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Color", Color) = 1, 1, 1, 1
        _Cutout ("Cutout", Range(0, 1)) = 0.5
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // Treat this material as transparent
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" }
        LOD 100

        // Set up alpha blending
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            // Add shader variables for our material properties.
            fixed4 _Color;
            float _Cutout;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                // Hide any part of the image that's darker than 
                // the current alpha value of the particle color
                col.a = saturate((col.r -_Cutout) * 10.0f);

                // Replace the visible color of the image
                // with the material color
                col.rgb = _Color.rgb;

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

In my examples all the displayed colour is coming from the particle system / material parameters, but you could just as easily have colour detail in your texture, and store the cutout gradient in the alpha channel.

Comment: High quality answer as always

Comment: @DMGregory, I am trying to use the code with a single quad. I made a script varying the ` _Cutout` property [see script](https://imgur.com/9hiUKZs). I am not certain how to implement the latter part -  `...but you could just as easily have colour detail in your texture, and store the cutout gradient in the alpha channel`. I tried `col.a = _MainTex;` but this gave me an error `Shader error in 'Unlit/RadialParticle': cannot implicitly convert from 'sampler2D' to 'half' at line 63 (on glcore)`

Comment: The colour-in-texture bit is optional - if you just want a flat colour, exposing that as a material property is more flexible. But if you want something more complicated, the steps would be... 1) Create the colour image you want. 2) Create the falloff gradient. 3) Put the falloff gradient into the alpha channel of the colour image (eg. using Photoshop channels tool) 4) Change `col.a = saturate((col.r - ...` to `col.a = saturate((col.a - ...` (I'd previously used the red channel arbitrarily to read the brightness of the greyscale image I was using, but instead you'll want the alpha channel)

Comment: You can't directly assign a texture to a numeric variable. You need to sample a specific point from the texture, which is what the `tex2D` function does.

Comment: for now I would like to get the single quad working. When I attach the material to the Sprite Renderer of my game object it becomes invisible both in scene view and game view.

Comment: Comments aren't great for troubleshooting, and it's 6AM here. ;) Would you be available to meet up in [chat] or a [Twitter direct message](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory) a little later?

Comment: Okay, let's meet later on in GDC :) (Game Development Chat), hopefully later in the afternoon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67390/discussion-between-dmgregory-and-superhypermegasomething).