# How to slowly render a Sprite in Unity over multiple frames (from its center)

Tags: unity, sprites

I'd like to slowly render a Unity Sprite of cracked ice, but from the middle of the sprite... over the course of 3-4 frames or so.

Then it would appear as if the ice crack is originating from the sprite's center.

So maybe the first 25% of the image would show on the first frame, and then each incremental frame would display another 25%.

[image]

I could save the image in Photoshop and then export a range of images, each with more of the ice crack showing... then save that as an animation and play that.

Is there an easier way to do this inside of Unity?  I plan to port this to mobile at some point, so a performant solution would be ideal. Thank you!

Comment: If it is only over 3-4 frames, it will look to the user almost the same as instantly. 4 frames in a 60 fps game is in 0.07s.

Comment: This is an education app, I'm only targeting 30 fps...  but also willing to go up to many more frames if that looks better!

Comment: [You can use the technique described here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149707/39518): use an alpha channel with a gradient from white where the sprite "should appear first" to black where the image "should appear last". Then you can vary an alpha threshold or offset to smoothly reveal the image in your custom shape sequence expressed by that gradient.